# Issue about NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I'm working on a project that uses both `NestedScrollView` and `RecyclerView`, and what I want to is:

The height of `RecyclerView` which the `childView` of `NestedScrollView` is changing according to amount of the child item, so if `RecyclerView`'s height below certain value, then only the `NestedScrollView` itself can response to scroll, and if the `RecyclerView`'s height above certain value, then they can just work normally.

so I want to know if there is a method of `NestedScrollView` that I can use to let `NestedScrollView` don't do `NestedScroll`, or could I make the child of `NestedScrollView` don't response to scroll but `NestedScrollView` it can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this attribute.I think this may help you.

```
   android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Like this,

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```